# To have Interactive data visualization in a website with around 300 million data live which gets updates by itself

Tags: data-visualization

A project is given to me- To have Interactive data visualization in a website with around 300 million data live which gets updated by itself. I tried to go with different libraries like Plotly but I couldn't find how to put that into a website. Please Suggest me. What should I do. Thank You.